# How can I animate a change to a UIButton's height without image warping?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation

I'm using `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` to hide a `UIButton` by changing its `frame.size.height` to `0`. However, as soon as the animation begins, the rounded rectangle and background immediately disappear while the button text clips off the bounds of the view.

The code I'm using is fairly straightforward:

```
CGRect newFrame = button.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    button.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

I've noticed that this only happens when i'm setting the height to 0. It seems that when the animation begins, the button is simply redrawn once in its final state. The animation is performed by scaling this static image from the original size to the final one. Since a button with a height of 0 can't be seen, it results in the whole roundrect disappearing (except for the text on the button, since it's a different view).

There must be a better way to do this so the animation doesn't look as weird. How can I make the animation behave the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work better if you do something like this?

```
CGRect newFrame = button.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 1;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 
                 animations:^{button.frame = newFrame;} 
                 completion:^{button.hidden = YES;}];
```

If you are using a system rounded rect button, it might also be that they do not like being resized below a certain level, it might work better with a custom button.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setting your button's alpha value to 0 in your animation? Or do you have to animate its height?

Comment: In my app, the button appears in a UITableView header, and I want the content below the button to slide up in its place as it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Take an image snapshot of the button, and do an affine transform animation rotating that view upwards, or changing the y scale.